# What is script class in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm learning groovy and could not comprehend this statement for the below piece of code.

Checked other related documentation but no luck. Can someone please help here ? Thanks.

`Variable annotation used for changing the scope of a variable within a script from being within the run method of the script to being at the class level for the script.`

Code snippet:

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field List awe = [1, 2, 3]
def awesum() { awe.sum() }
assert awesum() == 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

during compilation groovy transforms the script into a java class that extends [groovy.lang.Script](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html)

so, the code in question will be transformed to approximately this:

```
public class scriptXYZ extends groovy.lang.Script { 
    java.util.List awe 
    
    public scriptXYZ() {
        awe = [1, 2, 3]
    }

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        assert this.awesum() == 6
    }

    public java.lang.Object awesum() {
        return awe.sum()
    }
}
```

without `@Field` annotation the variable `awe` will be a part of `run()` method and obviously `awesum()` function will throw an error :

```
public class scriptXYZ extends groovy.lang.Script { 
    public scriptXYZ() {
    }

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        List awe = [1, 2, 3]
        assert this.awesum() == 6
    }

    public java.lang.Object awesum() {
        return awe.sum()
    }
}
```

in `groovyconsole` you can select menu `Script -> Inspect AST` to see a class generated for your script

[image]

Comment: That really helped, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

For reference the quote and the code in the question is from [Javadoc of
@Field](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html).  The full part for completeness:

> Variable annotation used for changing the scope of a variable within
> a script from being within the run method of the script to being at
> the class level for the script.
>
> The annotated variable will become a private field of the script class.
> The type of the field will be the same as the type of the variable.
> Example usage:
>
> ```
> import groovy.transform.Field
> @Field List awe = [1, 2, 3]
> def awesum() { awe.sum() }
> assert awesum() == 6
> ```
>
> In this example, without the annotation, variable awe would be
> a local script variable (technically speaking it will be a local
> variable within the run method of the script class). Such a local
> variable would not be visible inside the awesum method. With the
> annotation, awe becomes a private List field in the script class
> and is visible within the awesum method.

The reason why it is needed and to what "script" here means can be seen
by "disassembling" the generated code for a "groovy script" (a file just
containing the example code):

```
% cat x.groovy 
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field List awe = [1, 2, 3]
def awesum() { awe.sum() }
assert awesum() == 6
% groovyc x.groovy
% javap x
Compiled from "x.groovy"
public class x extends groovy.lang.Script { (1)
  java.util.List awe; (2)
  public static transient boolean __$stMC;
  public x();
  public x(groovy.lang.Binding);
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
  public java.lang.Object run(); (3)
  public java.lang.Object awesum(); (4)
  public void setAwe(java.util.List);
  protected groovy.lang.MetaClass $getStaticMetaClass();
  public static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup $getLookup();
}
```

(`(#)` additions are mine)

"Everything" to load and run on the JVM must a class.  Groovy compiled
the given file to something that extends `Script` (1), which is the
mentioned *script* in the docs.  (2) is the now generated *private
field*.  (3) is the *run method*.  And finally (4) is the generated
*awesum method*.

Comment: Really appreciate breaking down the code !!